# java RCP SWT the registerContextMenu(...) are lost

Tags: java, swt, rcp

In Java-SWT-RCP, I create several composites programmatically.

For each of them I register a menu:

```
eMenuService.registerContextMenu(this, "SourceViewer.popupmenu");
```

Everything work fine!

But, if I dispose one of the composites with the routine `.dispose`.

All the other composites lost the `popupmenu`.

Is there any method to unregister the menu properly, before it dispose the composite?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQsnM.png)

Comment: Generally you should not need to dispose of controls manually, SWT nearly always does this automatically at the correct time. But it is not at all clear from the question what exactly you are doing that causes the problem.